# Como resolver a referência "esta" em «A taxa de marinha é diferente daquela taxa dos bombeiros, pois esta é maior.»?

Tags: pronomes

Como resolver a referência "esta" neste caso?

> A taxa de marinha é diferente daquela taxa dos bombeiros, pois esta é maior.

E nas frases a seguir, como a referência seria resolvida?

> Este copo é diferente daquele prato, pois este é maior.

> Esta taxa de marinha é diferente daquela taxa dos bombeiros, pois esta é maior.

> Este amor é diferente daquele ódio, pois este é maior.

Comment: Sérgio, seria estudando os usos de "esse" e "este". Por exemplo, https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/este-ou-esse/. Interessante que a maioria dos sites que vi não fala desse uso da tua pergunta. Então, citando o Priberam: "[este] designativo de pessoa ou coisa de que se falou em último lugar." e "[esse] designa aquela de que se falou em penúltimo lugar". "Aquele" também funciona para isso, mas para termos antes do penúltimo ou outros, como "Brasil e Argentina existem, sendo este é menor que aquele" ou "Portugual, Brasil e São Tomé falam português, falando aquele há mais tempo".

Comment: @Schilive obrigado pelo comentário! Na frase da pergunta me parece intuitivo que se o pronome "aquela" já foi usado para referenciar a taxa dos bombeiros, o mesmo pronome deveria ser utilizado na segunda referência, assim a taxa da marinha seria a maior. Ou seja, a pergunta é sobre uma designação dupla. Algo do tipo "Esta é diferente daquela, pois esta é maior". Me parece que o segunda "esta" designa o mesmo objeto do primeiro. Mas no caso lendo a frase da pergunta foi claro pra você qual é maior? Ou também ficou na dúvida?

Comment: Sérgio, não entendi direito o teu comentário, desculpa. Vou considerar que leste o link. Vamos lá: quais são os usos de "este"? São espacial, catafórico do último termo e temporal. Não li texto, mas para mim não fazem sentido o uso espacial, pois o texto parece ser impessoal, nem catafórico, porque não há termo posterior e logo o texto acaba, nem temporal, já que não vejo nada que possa se relacionar a tempo. Logo, por eliminação, "este" se refere ao último termo, o termo mais próximo de "este". Se eu estiver correto, a que "este" se referiria?

Comment: Sérgio, por curiosidade. O jeito que eu aprendi a diferenciar "esse" e "este" é através de "aí" e "aqui". Não fica esquisito "aquela pessoa aqui"? Isso é porque "ali" e "lá" são conexos com "aquele", "aquela pessoa ali" soa bem e está certo. "Esse" é conexo com "aí" e "este", com "cá" e "aqui". Podes sempre colocar "aí" em "esse", e "cá" e "aqui" em "este", para veres se faz sentido. Então, imagina que estás pegando um livro e falas "esse livro é bom", mas não sabes se e culto ou não, então colocas "aí": "esse livro aí é bom".>>

Comment: >>O livro não está "aí" (esse), mas "aqui" (este), então, é culto usar "este livro é bom". Para entender o uso do termo mais perto, é só pensar "este" é o mais perto (este aqui) e "esse" é mais longe, mas nem tanto, (esse aí).

Comment: A taxa de marinha [taxa A] é diferente daquela taxa dos bombeiros [taxa B] e esta se refere a coisa mais perto gramaticalmente, na frase. Então ele tem razão porque a taxa B fica mais perto NA FRASE do que a taxa A. Não se trata de localização no espaço; se trata de localização discursiva, do lugar **na frase**.

Comment: @Lambie obrigado pelo comentário. No caso de "Este copo é diferente daquele prato, pois este é maior", me parece que o copo é maior, estou errado?

Comment: Obrigado @Schilive, seus comentários ajudaram bastante. Faz sentido que em um discurso impessoal a proximidade espacial não seja usada. Perguntei pra algumas pessoas e nessa frase "Esta taxa de marinha é diferente daquela taxa dos bombeiros, pois esta é maior" e a maioria respondeu que a taxa de marinha é maior. Ainda não entendi se a lógica que eles usaram é a proximidade espacial ou uma instanciação do termo "esta". Mas achei interessante a questão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No caso, o elemento «esta» seria um aposto distributivo. Assim, ele deve se referir a «taxa dos bombeiros» pela proximidade. Se eu substitui-se «aquela», seria a «taxa da marinha» por estar mais afastada.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas ainda fiquei na dúvida de qual proximidade deve ser priorizada, a proximidade na frase ou a espacial? Alterei a pergunta pra ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

ESTA se refere a taxa de marinha.